# How to show result of join 3 tables on CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

at library/comment.php

```
function getSelectedOneFieldJoin2TblGroupOrder($select, $table, $where, $join_table1, $join_condition1, $join_table2, $join_condition2, $order_by=null)
{
    $this->CI->db->select($select);
    $this->CI->db->from($table);
    
    $where2 = substr($where,6);
    $this->CI->db->where($where2);
          
        $this->CI->db->join($join_table1, $join_condition1, 'left');
        $this->CI->db->join($join_table2, $join_condition2, 'left');
            
    $this->CI->db->order_by($order_by);

    $query = $this->CI->db->get();
    $result = $query->row_array();

    if ($result) {
        return $result[$select];
    }
    
    return null; 
}
```

at controller/Dashboard.php

```
$res1=$this->common->getSelectedOneFieldJoin2TblGroupOrder(
" 'Product Order Placed' as activity_title, u.created_on as created_on, m.first_name AS created_by",
"tbl_product_order u",
"WHERE u.status != 2 and u.status != 0",
"tbl_package_master p", // $join_table1
"p.id = u.package_id",
"tbl_user_master m", // $join_table2
"m.user_id = u.user_id",
"u.created_on", "ASC"
 );
```

at view/dashboard.php

```
foreach($form_data as $Res)
{
    echo $Res['activity_title'] . " :: ";
    echo $Res['created_on'];
}
```

It show empty result.

When I change the line return **$result[$select];** to **return $result;** then it show 3 result but in array index no value...

How to show the result properly?

Comment: I'm just wondering: concerning your 2 last questions, it looks like you are over-complicating to create a quite simple sql query. Why are you using a function to deliver sql in pieces as parameters to build a final sql string?

Comment: i thought it is compulsory to delivery sql by function on CodeIgniter framework on new version 8 of mysql server?

Comment: where did you get this from? You are using CI3.x, which was developed way before mysql 8.0...  use standard "raw" SQL queries or the built-in functions of the query builder

Comment: yes, all my ci old websites get error everywhere when hosting server force to upgrade mysql 8.0.... so i need to fix all the error for my old existing clients' websites.

Comment: yes, that is unfortunately a necessary step you'll need to do. Or if you have enough paying clients, upgrade to get your own server, instead of a shared one. Anyway I've done this in the past and just went through the network tab of the browser to check which errors to fix (use localhost with the 8.0 mysql setting and make sure ENVIRONMENT is set to "development"). Then upload the fixes to production...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$query->row_array()` returns only the first row of the result set, as an array with the fields you specified in the `SELECT` as its keys.

I can't tell from your question whether you want to display only the first row or all of the rows in the result set, so:

- if you want to display all of the rows in the result set, change `$query->row_array()` to `$query->result_array()` and keep the `foreach` loop in the view.
- or if you want to display only the first row in the result set, keep the query as it is now (with `$query->row_array()`), and remove the `foreach` loop from the view, keeping only the `echo` statements:

  ```
    echo $form_data['activity_title'] . " :: ";
    echo $form_data['created_on'];
  ```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help. You are very kind and a life saver. May god bless you.